# Allowing a specific java certificate

Tags: java, certificate

We need to allow a specific java certificate for our users so that they don't have to accept the invalid certificate popup. Is there any known way of doing this? Is there anyway we can deploy a pre-defined JRE certificate store or anything like that?

Thanks

Comment: I would try this question on SO

Answer (score 3):

Managed to find a solution,
in `<user>`\application data\sun\java\deployment\security there's a file called trusted.certs which is the JRE certificate store. You can add and accept the certificates you need and deploy the file to the users through either a GPO or the mandatory profile if you are using mandatory profiles.

Answer (score 0):

You need to certify your application using the certificate. This process is called signing, and the java program that does it is jarsigner.exe, explained [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/jarsigner.html). However, this program is part of the java JDK and not the JRE.

Please note that after having signed the jar file, your clients only need the JRE for it to function. You only need install the JDK on the development machine.

For further info see:
[Understanding Signing and Verification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/intro.html)
[Lesson: API and Tools Use for Secure Code and File Exchanges](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/security/sigcert/index.html)

Comment: you did not read the question properly. We didn't develop the application, nor will they who properly sign it. It does not matter, I managed to find a solution.

Comment: Sorry, guess I had answered too many questions by novices the last few days.